# ¿Cómo añadir una cabezera http a una petición SOAP en php?

Tags: php, http, soap

Me encontré con el problema de añadir una cabezera `http` a una petición de tipo `SOAP` en [php](/questions/tagged/php), lo estaba intentando realizar de esta forma:

```
$resourceEndPoint = "http://192.168.10.28:55823/Servicios/Pagos.svc";

$MPClient = new SoapClient($resourceEndPoint . "?wsdl",
    array(
        'soap_version'  => 'SOAP_1_2',
        'location'      => $resourceEndPoint,
        'trace'         => true,
        'exceptions'    => true
    )
);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://192.168.10.28:55823/Servicios/', 
                         'Authorization',
                         'QWxndW5hQ2FkZW5h');

$MPClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la forma en que lo estaba realizando era incorrecta ya que la cabezera no iba a ser leída como `http` si no, como `soap`, pude resolver mi problema añadiendo la cabezera por medio de un `stream_context` directamente en las opciones de mi cliente `soap` de la siguiente manera:

```
$resourceEndPoint = "http://192.168.10.28:55823/Servicios/Pagos.svc";

$MPClient = new SoapClient($resourceEndPoint . "?wsdl",
    array(
        'soap_version'  => 'SOAP_1_2',
        'location'      => $resourceEndPoint,
        'trace'         => true,
        'exceptions'    => true,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => 'Authorization: QWxndW5hQ2FkZW5h'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```